# How to distribute Identical Fruits (Stars-Bars Fails here)

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways 3 oranges, 2 apples and 1 mango can be distributed among 4 persons, such that each gets atleast one fruit. (Fruits of same type are identical).

How tried to use stars-Bars method but its obvious it will not give the correct answer. How can we approach this question. ( I tried to write all the cases but its not a good way to solve, I think !!!)

Comment: This is not an easy problem to generalize, but thankfully the numbers here are very small.  Recognize that there are two possible cases: one of the persons will get three fruit while each other person gets one, or two people will get two fruit while the other two get just one.

Comment: Yes, I tried that thing but in those cases also we have multiple cases for example if one person is getting 2 fruits it can be (2 O or 2 A or 1 A 1 M etc). There are high chances of missing cases

Comment: If you insist on finding a different way, my next instinct is to approach by inclusion-exclusion.  Stars and bars works here if we ignore the condition that everyone needs to get at least one fruit.  (distribute the oranges.  multiply by the number of ways to distribute the apples, etc...).  Now, subtract the number of ways where the first person got nothing.  Also the number of ways the second person got nothing (*same result as number where first person got nothing*) etc..., add back number of ways two people got nothing, subtract number of ways three people got nothing etc...

Comment: Either way, I get a final answer of $220$ that you can check your work against.

Comment: Another idea: imagine first dividing the fruit into four bundles and then assigning the bundles to the people. If all the bundles are different, the assignment can be done in $4!$ different ways. There are only a few ways to create identical bundles, which you can count separately.

Answer (score 2):

Approach by inclusion-exclusion:

Find the number of ways we could distribute the fruit if we didn't care about the restriction that everyone needs to receive at least one fruit (of any kind).  To do this, distribute the oranges in $\binom{3+4-1}{4-1}=\binom{6}{3}$ ways.  Then distribute the apples in $\binom{2+4-1}{4-1}=\binom{5}{2}$ ways and then the apple in $\binom{4}{1}$ ways.  Finally, multiply these together for the overall count of $\binom{6}{3}\binom{5}{2}\binom{4}{1}$ ways.

Now, let us get rid of the ways in which at least one person didn't get any fruit starting by subtracting the number where specifically the first person didn't get any fruit.  Well, the way to count this is the same as before just with one fewer person, giving $\binom{5}{3}\binom{4}{2}\binom{3}{1}$ ways.  Taking into account that there are four choices for who to be left out adjusts this number further.

Continuing with inclusion-exclusion correctly requires that we then add back the number of ways in which at least two specific people were left out, and then subtracting again where three people were left out, etc... Note that it is impossible for all four people to have received no fruit simultaneously since presumably the fruit has to go to somebody.

We get as a final total then:

$$\binom{6}{3}\binom{5}{2}\binom{4}{1}-4\binom{5}{3}\binom{4}{2}\binom{3}{1}+\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{3}\binom{3}{2}\binom{2}{1}-\binom{4}{3}\binom{3}{3}\binom{2}{2}\binom{1}{1}=220$$

Comment: Thanx @Jmoravitz